# How can I use the new Cypress Component Test Runner for an Angular Project?

Tags: angular, cypress

I'm using Cypress for integration tests and want to use also, if it's possible, the Component Test Runner for testing single components.
At the present time I only found descriptions for setting it up with React or View but not with Angular.

When I try to start `node_modules/.bin/cypress open-ct` I get following Error:
`` Error: It is required to register dev-server plugin that implements `dev-server:start` event for component testing. ``

I tried to use the suggested implementation from Cypress in my pluginsFile:

```
const { startDevServer } = require('@cypress/webpack-dev-server')
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config.js')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('dev-server:start', (options) => {
    return startDevServer({ options, webpackConfig })
  })

  return config
}
```

but it still fails.

Is there a chance to get it running with Angular?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, got it fixed by myself, if somebody is interested.

I updated my index.js file in the Cypress folder to:

```
const { startDevServer } = require('@cypress/webpack-dev-server')
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config.js')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('dev-server:start', (options) => {
    return startDevServer({ options, webpackConfig })
  })

  return config
}
```

Installed "webpack": "^4.44.0" and "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0", created "webpack.config.js" with this code:

```
// cypress/webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  },
  node: { fs: "empty", child_process: "empty", readline: "empty" },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: [
          {
          loader: "ts-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

in Cypress-Folder.

Removed all node-modules and package-lock.json and did an `npm i`.

Now it works fine.

Comment: Did you run your tests on Windows? Your response helped me a lot with running the tests, but now my tests are timing out waiting for the browser and it looks like it's only Windows-related issue.

Comment: No, my tests are running on MacOS. I often have the same issue that my first test times out. But when I restart the test it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem once using Cypress component testing in a more complicated way, by wrapping it in another package.

Anyway, if you have tried using `--config '<config>'` option, make sure `<config>` is not like `{"component": {"pluginsFile": "path/to/index.js", ...}}`. Hoist the options in `component` to the top level, like `{"pluginsFile": "path/to/index.js", ...}`, otherwise Cypress will try to generate both empty Cypress.json and cypress/plugins/index.js files.